# Emails Not Sending in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Before I explain my issue, I first want to clarify that I feel as though I've tried more or less every solution I've seen on Stack Overflow and none of them have worked for me.

The issue I'm experiencing is that no emails are being sent when a user requests for a password reset. I'll add some details/context below.

settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get("EMAIL_ADDRESS")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("EMAIL_PASSWORD")
```

I've added my email address and password into my env.py file and I have actually received a notification on my phone notifying me that someone is trying to access my account e.g. an email is trying to be sent from another source.

I've also turned **App Access** on Google off.

[image]

I'm lost for ideas at this point so any support would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't supposed to be on there! It's actually smtp rather than console.

Comment: What are you using for authentication?